# C++ how to handle text file (opening - writing -closing)

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that display a menu which gives the users 4 options:
1.Specify the filename (this step need to be executed first).
2.Write data to that file (name and score for example).
3.Display the content of a file.
4.Close the file.

So I am not able to open a file. My code so far is working fine up to the "validation of user inputs" step (using while loop). But I still cannot get the file open.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you and please excuse my poor English.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    const int SPECIFY_NAME = 1,
        ADD_NAME_GAME_SCORE = 2,
        DISPLAY = 3,
        CLOSE_FILE = 4;

    //Variables:
    int choice;
    char end;

    string name;
    double gameScore;

    ifstream inputFile;
    string filename;

    //ofstream outputFile;

    do
    {
        //Display the menu:
        cout << "\n\t\tPlease choose your option from the menu below\n\n"
            << "1. Specify a file name\n"
            << "2. Add a name and game score to the file\n"
            << "3. Display the content of a file\n"
            << "4. Close the file\n\n"
            << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        //Validate user input:
        while (choice < 1 || choice > 1)
        {
            if (choice > 0 && choice <= 4)
            {
                cout << "Please enter 1 to specify a file first: ";
                cin >> choice;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Please enter a valid menu choice: ";
                cin >> choice;
            }
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            //Get the file name when user input 1:
            cout << "Type in the file name: ";
            cin >> filename;

            //Open the file:
            inputFile.open(filename);

            while (!inputFile)
            {
                cout << "Please check your file name and type it in correctly: ";
                cin >> filename;

                inputFile.open(filename);
            }

            cout << "Congratulation! You got the file open successfully.\n";
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Please type in your name: ";
            cin >> name;

            while (name.empty())
            {
                cout << "You did not type in your name.\n"
                    << "Please type again: ";
                cin >> name;
            }

            cout << "Please enter the game score: ";
            cin >> gameScore;

            while (gameScore < 0)
            {
                cout << "You have entered a negative number for game score.\n"
                    << "Please type in a possitive number: ";
                cin >> gameScore;
            }
        }

    }
    while (choice != 1);
    {
        cout << "press any key then ENTER to exit the program\n";
        cin >> end;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check you are using the correct path to the file

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's wrong with the program you've written so far? What help do you need?